# Convert date to end of day

Tags: javascript

I get time in milliseconds from the server. I convert it to Date and get - 
Mon Jul 22 2013 11:16:01 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time) as the date in the record.

I want to separate out data of Monday, Tuesday etc into arrays. I am thinking of converting this date to Mon Jul 22 2013 23:59:59 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time) and then filter out the records.

How can i change the date to the required end of the day time? or is there an easier way to do this ?

Comment: I don't quite understand what it is you're after. Could you show an example of the result you're looking for?

Comment: Usually people just zero out the hour, minute, sec and ms and use the start of the day. That works pretty well unless you have to compare millisecond times to check for events on that day and even that isn't hard.

Comment: Which time zone do you want to use: client's TZ or some other one (like GMT)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could always construct a new DateTime object just using the year, month and day properties from the existing date, like so:

```
var actualDate = new Date(); // 2013-07-30 17:11:00
var endOfDayDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear()
                           ,actualDate.getMonth()
                           ,actualDate.getDate()
                           ,23,59,59); // 2013-07-30 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 8):

For future visitors, just use

```
const start = new Date();
const end = new Date();
start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
end.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using http://momentjs.com:

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
var endOfDay = moment(now).endOf("day").toDate(); // Wed Jan 20 2016 23:59:59 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var actualDate = new Date()
var eodDate = new Date(Math.floor(actualDate.getTime()/86400000+1)*86400000 + actualDate .getTimezoneOffset()*60000 - 1000)
```

where 86400000 are total milliseconds in a day

Answer (score -1):

If two Date Objects are on the same day then they have the same Date String:

```
new Date('1374488161000').toDateString()
=> "Tue Jul 30 2013"

new Date('13744917610403').toDateString()
=> "Tue Jul 30 2013"
```

Although a rather naive method of comparing days, it's probably the simplest comparison.